# Easier to use multiple Devise models or one User model that other models have a user_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

(Using Devise & Cancancan)

I have multiple kinds of users that need to login. Manager, Chef, Clerk. They each have different roles and relationships to other models in the database.

Is it easier to use multiple devise models, customize abilities?

Alternatively, I could have Manager, Chef and Clerk have a user_id they use to login.

So far I'm going with the former, multiple devise models. But if it's easier the other way I'd like to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you share the same methods, than you should only have 1 model. It is much easier to maintain. The only reason I would use multiple models is when they are different in the way you want to login for example.

Cancan has a tutorial on how to set this up.

`https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization`

There are other ways, like using a Role model.

Hope this helps.

Comment: They will have different methods due to their logic differences. I'm thinking about using Cancanca with multiple models, does that sound right? (Possibly Rollify if I need finer tuned()